# Einstein would be proud

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Really amazing, is what most people say I am,
> Of ways to move, I'm the fastest way out of a jam.
>
> Some people think I'm a hole, but not quite,
> Expect me to be 4D, you'd be right.
>
> Now be like an ant or a line, my twist awaits,
> Sometimes orange or sometimes blue, are my gates.

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are:

> A Portal

Really amazing, is what most people say I am,

> Portals are amazing

Of ways to move, I'm the fastest way out of a jam.

> Portals are definitely a quick way to get from place to place

Some people think I'm a hole, but not quite,

> Portals may seem like holes, but they're not

Expect me to be 4D, you'd be right.

> It is hypothesized that [tessarects are the key to opening portals](https://www.quora.com/How-would-a-tesseract-open-a-portal)

Now be like an ant or a line, my twist awaits,

> A portal/wormhole is the shortest distance between two points in spacetime, as is a line. Additionally, ants [optimize their routes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) to get around quickly

Sometimes orange or sometimes blue, are my gates.

> In the game [Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game)), the two colors of portals are orange and blue

As for the title:

> A [wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) would be a "non-trivial solution of the Einstein field equations," which I'm sure he'd be proud.   Additionally, thanks to @M.Herzkamp, taking the first letter of each line gives ROSENS, referring to the [Einstein-Rosen Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole), showing that two black holes can be connected by a wormhole, or portal

Comment: That is correct, however, your ant and line one is off. Hint: Think of a piece of paper example.

Comment: Also, there is a secret hint I'd like for people to find.

Comment: Concerning the first letter of each line, the Einstein-Rosen bridge comes to mind. Maybe he means "Rosen's bridge"?

Comment: The ant line refers to the analogy of an Ant walking on a strip of paper he is confined to 2d, but the ant can walk in 3d around a string. This is the analogy of how a portal could work.

Comment: @wolfram42 not that tough Experiment where the ant could go across a entire Paper with one by folding it side? (Folding of Space/Wormholes)

Comment: Ants and paper.. what comes to my mind is the Ercher's [moebius strip](http://www.mcescher.com/gallery/recognition-success/mobius-strip-ii/)

Comment: Ants and Paper example reminds me of Mrs. Which explaining a tesseract in *A Wrinkle in Time*—Madeleine L'Engle.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Black hole

Really amazing, is what most people say I am,
Of ways to move, I'm the fastest way out of a jam.

> They can pull things into them selves with their strong gravitational pull.

Some people think I'm a hole, but not quite,
Expect me to be 4D, you'd be right.

> They are not a hole but a round clump of dark matter.

Now be like an ant or a line, my twist awaits,
Sometimes orange or sometimes blue, are my gates.

> This might refer to the light that doesn't come out of it. Also the ant trail may refer to the fact they scientists can trace a trail of neutrinos from large intergalactic power sources.

Also the title

> Einstein researched black holes.

Comment: Excellent answer, but not quite the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> **Gravity**?

`Really amazing, is what most people say I am,`

> **Gravity** really is **amazing** — without it, you would never have learnt how to **walk**.

`Of ways to move, I'm the fastest way out of a jam.`

> A reference to the TV show, [**Gravity** Falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Falls), in the seventh episode of the first season, [*Double Dipper*](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Dipper_Pines). Basically, the main character ([Dipper Pines](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Dipper_Pines)) wants to impress a girl that he likes ([Wendy Corduroy](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Wendy_Corduroy)) and, in particular, wants to ask her to dance. His plan: make some clones of himself. 
>  
>  Unfortunately, his plan goes horribly wrong and is ruined by a clone referred to as [Paper **Jam** Dipper](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Paper_Jam_Dipper) who was made by accident. Then, all the clones turn on Dipper — but in the end, all the clones [make contact with water due to **gravity** (the water falls on them)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3b9jldOrTI) and are all defeated.

`Some people think I'm a hole, but not quite,`

> **Gravity** is distorted space-time;${}^1$ when an object has mass, it **bends space** (changes its shape and "weaves out its fabric") and **stretches it out**, thus making [gravity](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/what-is-gravity/en/). You might as well call it a **hole**... but not quite (as it is more like a **curve**). 
>  <sub>${}^1$More about distortions in particular can be found [here](https://www.science.org.au/curious/space-time/gravity).</sub>

`Expect me to be 4D, you'd be right.`

> Gravity used to be considered the fourth dimension for several years (the theory being [first proposed in May, $2006$](https://today.duke.edu/2006/05/braneworld.html)). 
>   <sub>The only flaw is, it has been proven *not* to be ([here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14725/could-gravity-be-the-4th-dimension) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-gravity-4th-dimensional)), so it is *not* right to say it is.</sub>

`Now be like an ant or a line, my twist awaits,`

> Gravity has so much power, we are like **ants** compared to it; its power is **pulling** and **twisting** space-time, acting as a very **strong force** (for us, at least); and it always awaits when we **jump**.

`Sometimes orange or sometimes blue, are my gates.`

> Photons${}^1$ (a quantum particle that makes up **light**) [orbit a black hole](https://www.universetoday.com/110682/can-light-orbit-a-black-hole/) (creating what is known as the [photon sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere)), which is [surrounded by **gravity**](https://briankoberlein.com/2015/08/21/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole/). Light is composed of all kinds of colours, including **orange** and **blue**. 
>  <sub>${}^1$Go [here](https://www.universetoday.com/74027/what-are-photons/) or [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon).</sub>

---

**Title:**

`Einstein would be proud`

> ...of the riddle — the answer might be gravity, which is something that Einstein (and his theories and equations) are heavily related to.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Light

Really amazing, is what most people say I am,
Of ways to move, I'm the fastest way out of a jam.

> Nothing is faster than the speed of light

Some people think I'm a hole, but not quite,
Expect me to be 4D, you'd be right.

> the 4D light field is defined as radiance along rays in empty space

Now be like an ant or a line, my twist awaits,
Sometimes orange or sometimes blue, are my gates.

> Light can be orange or blue, and it can be treated like a wave or a particle

Title:

> Einstein's most widely known work, E = mc^2, involves the speed of light, c.

Comment: Nice answer, but not quite what I'm looking for.